# How to adjust a 3S BMS to connect a 2S Lithium ion battery pack to it?

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion, protection, over-voltage-protection, bms

I have a 2S Lithium ion battery pack and a 3S 18650 BMS protection board. I need to connect the pack to the board. While researching, I've noticed that this can be done by connecting a component across the B1 and B2 pins, but I am unsure what that component is. Would be grateful for any insight on how to adjust the board and also any resource to understand the purpose of this component.

[image]

Comment: There is no general rule how to do this. Some BMS offer this feature, others don't.

Answer (score 1):

With that BMS you can't. It's not doable. Just buy a 2S BMS

Comment: How can you be sure? Two of the possible 5 cells are already disabled by jumpers. Following this logic, disabling a third cell may be an option.

Comment: Because the control circuit expects a minimum power-supply voltage. Two cells provide too low a voltage (especially at the end of charge, under load), while 3 cells provide sufficient voltage,

Answer (score 0):

You just need to connect b2 and b3 together, i tried on many types of bms it works well,
For using 4s bms to 3s same method connect b3 and b4 together
Also for using 4s bms to 2s connect b2 b3 and b4 together